# Separar itens de uma string utilizando Regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Preciso separar os itens de uma string em um array utilizando C# e Regex, poderiam me ajudar?

A string é a seguinte:
`required|email|min:2|max:255`

Há algumas regras que eu queria adequar:

- Separar os itens principais delimitados pela barra `|`.
- Ignorar caso haja uma barra no final da string, exemplo `required|email|`.
- Separar itens que possuam um valor, exemplo `min:2` e `max:255`.

Comment: Os itens separados por "`:`" vão ficar juntos em um mesmo item ou eles serão totalmente separados?

Comment: Juntos em um mesmo item.

Comment: Se os itens de "`:`" tiverem que ficar juntos de alguma maneira, acho que a resposta que eu te dei não vai resolver. Você teria que, por exemplo, criar uma lista de _Array_, sendo que maioria dos _Array_ teriam só uma posição e os que tivessem mais de uma posição seriam dos itens separados por "`:`"... Se precisar disso mesmo só comenta aqui que eu mudo a resposta!

Comment: Exatamente, o que preciso é de algo que gere um array onde os itens que forem separados por `:` sejam inclusos em um outro nível, onde a primeira string é a key e a segunda string é o valor, exemplo: `["required", ["max", 255], ["min": 6], "email"]`.

Comment: Resposta editada para incluir uma solução pra essa situação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recomendo usar o `Split` normal, normalmente é mais eficiente que Regex.

Se todos os valores tiverem que ser separados, basta dar `Split` pelos dois caracteres e usar a opção de ignorar divisões vazias: `Split(new char[] { ':', '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`.

Se os valores separados por "`:`" precisarem ficar juntos, a solução complica um pouco. Um dos problemas é que não existe `Array` ou `List` de tipos diferentes no `C#`, então uma alternativa seria `List` de `Array`:

```
var texto = "required|email|min:2|max:255";

var itensSeparados = texto.Split(new char[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(x => x.Split(new char[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    .ToList();

foreach (var item in itensSeparados)
{
    if (item.Length == 1)
        ; // Item único
    else
        ; // Itens separados por ":"
}
```